# I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete but not show in dashboard

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have problem with Fabric. its a test project for find problem and do everything step by step in fabric documents, but i don't know what is mistake. please help me.

My Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.testtt"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.testtt">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="9fd0b323bad2f5dae063288c94fd3a2317faa104"
            />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Main Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    // TODO: Move this to where you establish a user session
    logUser();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
private void logUser() {
    // TODO: Use the current user's information
    // You can call any combination of these three methods
    Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier("12345");
    Crashlytics.setUserEmail("user@fabric.io");
    Crashlytics.setUserName("Test User");
}

public void forceCrash(View view) {
    throw new RuntimeException("This is a crash");
}
```

After all, and error and testing, but nothing is still displayed on the dashboard. 
I do everything step by step from fabric documents.
I have this problem for a few days, and anyway I've tested it, but I still have not gotten a result and does not display anything in the fabric dashboard. **ApiKey is correct and I'm sure of it**.

(sorry for English)